# PE ImageBase presence in PDB

Tags: pe, address, pdb

Is `ImageBase` of a PE binary present in its PDB or can it only be retrieved from the binary?

I have studied both [Microsoft's PDB sources](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-pdb) and [LLVM docs](https://llvm.org/docs/PDB/index.html) without much luck finding it.

In the [DBI stream](https://llvm.org/docs/PDB/DbiStream.html#optional-debug-header-stream) there exist section headers with section RVAs, but I couldn't find any trace of their corresponding VAs or the base address itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this information is not stored within the PDB files in any recent versions.

Microsoft's [DIA SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-interface-access/debug-interface-access-sdk?view=vs-2022) used for dumping information contained in PDB files does provide a method named [`get_virtualAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-interface-access/idiasymbol-get-virtualaddress?view=vs-2022) (as opposed to [`get_relativeVirtualAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-interface-access/idiasymbol-get-relativevirtualaddress?view=vs-2022)) which should, in theory, return the real virtual address of a static symbol (segment, section, frame data etc.), however both of these methods currently return the same value (RVA) in all test cases I've tried. The implementations of two methods *are* different though, suggesting that there could be some use cases where the VAs are in fact stored within the data.

Keep in mind that the PDB format dates back to 90s, so if I had to guess I'd say that the actual VA's were contained within PDB files back before ASLR was introduced. This is, of course, only speculation on my part.

Comment: That's what I assumed too and instead extracted the imagebase directly from binary with IDAPython, thanks